# withCount Laravel funciona solo con una relación

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

tengo la siguiente query

```
$level = Level::find($id); // ID Level
$posts = $level->posts()
        ->with('category', 'image', 'tags')
        ->withCount(['comments'])->get();
```

El resultado me devuelve los posts de un X nivel con su categoría, imagen, etiquetas y el numero de comentarios por cada post (**$post->comments_count**). Funciona bien. Pero en esa misma query que cuenta los comentarios de un post quisiera traer el numero de posts por nivel, he intentado así:

```
$posts = $level->posts()
        ->with('category', 'image', 'tags')
        ->withCount(['comments', 'posts'])->get();
```

Y con

```
$posts = $level->posts()
        ->with('category', 'image', 'tags')
        ->withCount(['comments', 'posts as postCount'])->get();
```

Pero no funciona.

Este es mi modelo Nivel y su relación con Posts

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Post::class, User::class);
}
```

Este es mi modelo Post y su relación con comments

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

Se que hay otras formas pero la verdad me gustaría saber si es posible hacerlos con una sola query como los comments.

---

Otras Formas que he intentado son

```
$np = $level->withCount(['posts'])->get();
```

Y me trae el siguiente array

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Oro","posts_count":11},
{"id":2,"name":"Plata","posts_count":25},
{"id":3,"name":"Bronce","posts_count":0}]
```

Pero si imprimo **$np->posts_count** dice **Property [posts_count] does not exist on this collection instance.**

---

Puedo hacer lo siguiente y esto si me trae el numero de posts, pero quiero hacerlo en una sola linea como ya lo dije antes.

```
$np = $level->posts->count();
```

Gracias

Comment: Es posible. No sé si necesitas para algo el Level o sólo necesitas los Post, porque desde el inicio ya estás haciendo una consulta sobre Level y luego otra sobre los Post relacionados a ese Level

Comment: Necesito el nivel porque consulto los posts de cada nivel (Oro, Plata, Bronce). Cuando hago click a un nivel, envío el ID del nivel y consulto los posts de todos los usuarios que tienen ese nivel, justo por eso quiero contar los posts por cada nivel. Algo como lo muestro en el array que hago usando la variable $np

Comment: Pero con sólo el id del nivel también podes obtener los posts de ese nivel, por eso preguntaba. De todas maneras teniendo la colección de posts en la variable, podes obtener la cantidad con `$cantidad = $posts->count();`

Comment: Pero eso ya lo tengo, lo especifiqué en la pregunta, quiero saber si se puede en la misma línea de withCount()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tal no podrás hacerlo en la misma línea del **withCount()** porque a esta le pasas la relación de tu modelo como parámetro así **withCount('relation')**.

Cuando desde un nivel consultas sus posts() te metes al modelo Post, el modelo Post tiene según tu código, una relación **comments** pero no tienes una relación posts() dentro de Post Model porque no se hace así. Entonces tal cual lo tienes tendrías que consultar el numero de posts por cada nivel con una instrucción (línea de código) adicional.

```
$totalPosts = $level->posts->count();
```

Te dejo [este ejemplo](https://www.laraveltip.com/como-obtener-la-cantidad-de-registros-relacionados-con-eloquent/) para que veas como puedes hacer otras cosas con withCount() siempre y cuando exista una relación en el modelo que estas utilizando.

Comment: Gracias, con tu ayuda y la del ejemplo del link pude comprenderlo mejor